# How to read the next word using getline() in a file based on an information given in C++?

Tags: c++, getline

I am very new in C++ and I need some help with the file operation. I am reading a file using `getline()`, and I when I get a colon, or semicolon etc. I want to store the next word as an element of a class. I used `getline()` to read from a file and store a specific value as a class element:

```
void read(string f){
    string s;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(f.c_str());

    configFile c;

    while(fin){
        getline(fin, s, ' '); //reading from file, terminates when finds space
        s = small(s); // converting to lower case
        if (s = "version/phase:"){
            c.ver = getline() // want to store the next word in c.ver
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==`.  If it doesn't work, please post the complete code, with `include` and `using` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as below.

```
void read(string f){
string s;
ifstream fin;
fin.open(f.c_str());

configFile c;

while(fin>>s){
    //getline(fin, s, ' '); //reading from file, terminates when finds space
    s = small(s); // converting to lower case
    if (s == "version/phase:"){
        fin>>s;
        c.ver = s;// getline() // want to store the next word in c.ver
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't mean `if (s = "version/phase:"){` - you need to say `if (s == "version/phase:"){` to compare.  And `c.ver = s;` stores the current word but he wants to store the NEXT word (the actual version number)  Instead of `c.ver = s;` maybe `getline(fin, c.ver, ' ');` or `fin >> c.ver;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you say what does fin>>s do?

Comment: Read string(delimited by whitespcae)  from `fin` stream to `s`